# Copy data from one cell to another - Google scripts

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having issues copying data from one cell to another in my google spreadsheet by using a google script. I can get the value of the cell that I desire but I have issues copying it to a different cell. Here is my code.

```
var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logKey);
var value = sourceSS.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName).getRange(sourceCell).getValue();
var logSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logKey);
var sheet = logSS.getSheetByName(logSheetName);
logSS.getSheetByName(logSheetName).getRange(logCell).setValue(value);
```

I have now changed my code as shown in the image below with the error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNGYf.png)

Comment: Also, when debugging my code, it looks like I'm able to populate the object logSS but the var sheet seems to be NULL. IDK why this doesn't work because I am able to do that on the second line of code.

Comment: Additionally, I get the error message: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help Augustine. I had issues with opening the correct sheet within my spreadsheet. Here is my solution:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logKey);
var value = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName).getRange(sourceCell).getValue();
ss.getSheetByName(logSheetName).getRange(logCell).setValue(value);
```

The key was to verify that I had the correct variable names and I wasn't trying to open the same spreadsheet twice.

Answer (score 1):

Update (6-2-17)

If you are logging within the same SpreadSheet, then this code might work:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logKey);
var value = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName).getRange(sourceCell).getValue();
ss.getSheetByName(logSheetName).getRange(logCell).setValue(value);
```

---

---

First, did you realize that you are using logKey twice for both the logger and source spreadsheets? In both cases (lines 1 and 3) you have: SpreadsheetApp.openById(logKey), opening the same spreadsheet.

I made two spreadsheets and ran your code, switching the reference variables:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("wefdf5y65t45tO45tWy544f8hc10kdjEfgrrf4H-f48u");
  var value = sourceSS.getSheetByName("SourceSheet").getRange("A1").getValue();
  var logSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("f4h738H9GH07ghTf5rtfYtrf4h67566dytrdhe478293");
  var sheet = logSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  logSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1").setValue(value);
}
```

And it runs perfectly and populates into the logging spreadsheet properly, so it means that one of the following variables is off in your code (I can't see how you declared them):

- logKey
- sourceSheetName
- sourceCell
- logSheetName
- logCell

---

I get the error message: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

- Again, this happens when I mess up the variables above, specifically, sourceSheetName. For example, if I set that variable to "SourceShe" instead of "SourceSheet", then Google Sheets can't find it and it is null.

I think all of your problems are because of some misspellings when declaring the variables beforehand.

Comment: I am attempting to access the same spreadsheet but a different sheet within the same spreadsheet...

Comment: Ah, okay, then you only need to open the SpreadSheet once. The SpreadSheet is the entire document (all sheets), the "sheet" is a specific tab within the spreadsheet. I will update and write some code so it is more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried exactly that and still can't get it to work. I added some more details to my post with a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm an idiot. It has been working from the beginning for me. I was saving it in the correct sheet that I wanted to but I was looking in the incorrect sheet for the data.... #embarrassed